# How to join and merge multiple collections in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have three collections which I want to merge in one response. I have tried with `$lookup` but it was not working. The sample schema's and expected response sample attached. The issue is that, it is not merging into one array.

**Sample diagram:**
[image]

Collection 1: **product**

```
db.collection("product").findOne({"_id": ObjectId(id), "uid":uid})

 Response:{
   "_id":"12345",
   "uid":"537354",
   "name":"toyota"
}
```

Collection 2: **car_types**

```
db.collection('car_types').find({"$or":[{"uid":uid,"car_type":"custom"},{"car_type":"default"}]})

Response: [
   {
      "_id":"9987",
      "car_type":"default",
      "title":"Sports"
   },
   {
      "_id":"9988",
      "uid":"537354",
      "car_type":"custom",
      "title":"Trucks"
   }
]
```

Collection 3: **car_images**

```
db.collection("car_images").find({"car_id":car_id, "uid":uid})

    Response:
    [
   {
      "_id":"56433",
      "uid":"537354",
      "product_id":"12345",
      "type_id":"9987",
      "img_src":"cart.jpg"
   },
   {
      "_id":"42453",
      "uid":"537354",
      "product_id":"12345",
      "type_id":"9988",
      "img_src":"mini.jpg"
   }
]
```

**Expected Response:**

```
{
   "product":{
   "_id":"12345",
   "uid":"537354",
   "car_id":"9922",
   "name":"toyota"
},
   "car_types":[
   {
      "_id":"9987",
      "car_type":"default",
      "title":"Sports",
      "img_src":"cart.jpg"
   },
   {
      "_id":"9988",
      "uid":"537354",
      "car_type":"custom",
      "title":"Trucks",
      "img_src":"mini.jpg"
   }
]
}
```

Comment: In `car_types` collection how did you get two `_id`'s with same value (`"_id":9987`) ? Also what is the relation between `car_data` & `car_types` ?

Comment: @whoami Sorry, Those `_id` different. I updated the question. Secondly, there is relation between `car_data` & `car_type` is uid.

Comment: Did you miss ro present uid in sample doc of car_data ? As query itself won’t work if uid is not present in actual doc..

Comment: @whoami right!! updated

Comment: In `car_types` default type don't have `uid` . Only custom require `uid`

Comment: So when you join `car_data` & `car_types` collections do you just want docs from `car_types` where `uid` matches or along with that do you want docs from `car_types` where `{"car_type":"custom"},{"car_type":"default"}` ? Also is `uid` number in `car_data` (Vs) string in `car_types` ? what is your DB version ?

Comment: @whoami, I have updated question more briefly with sample diagram.

Comment: Ok going back to my earlier comment - do you just want docs from `car_types` where `uid` matches with doc in `product` or along with that do you want docs from `car_types` where `{"car_type":"custom"},{"car_type":"default"}` ? Also can you confirm when joining `car_images` it's based on `car_types` data right nothing to do with `product` doc ?

Comment: @whoami I want `docs from car_types where {"car_type":"custom"},{"car_type":"default"}` .  car_images based on `product_id,type_id and uid`. I guess, there need to implement two filters. first filter by `product_id` than `type_id` and `uid`

Comment: Check this query (https://mongoplayground.net/p/YcBJQybNpsL), I would say mapping `car_types` & `car_images` can be easily done in programming code, It would be easy to get data from different collections using `$lookup` than getting data clubbed, So I would better offload that work to code after getting this needed data from DB, let me know if it works will add it as an answer with explanation..

Comment: @whoami OMG!!! It works, you saved my day .. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below aggregation query which uses [multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup):

```
db.product.aggregate([
    /** lookup on `car_types` to pull in docs where if `uid are equal + car_type is custom` or `car_type is default` */
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "car_types",
        let: { productUID: "$uid" }, /** Create a local variable */
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              $expr: { 
                  "$or": [ 
                  { $and: [ { $eq: [ "$uid", "$$productUID" ] }, { $eq: [ "$car_type", "custom" ] } ] },
                   { $eq: [ "$car_type", "default" ] } 
                ] 
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        as: "car_types"
      }
    },
    /** lookup on `car_images`, to pull in docs where if `type_id` exists in array of `car_types._id` or uid's are equal */
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "car_images",
        let: { car_typesID: "$car_types._id", productUID: "$uid" },
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: { $expr: { $or: [ { $in: [ "$type_id", "$$car_typesID" ] }, { $eq: [ "$uid", "$$productUID" ] } ] } }
          }
        ],
        as: "car_images"
      }
    }
  ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YcBJQybNpsL)

Comment: I want to add one more condition in `car_images` which is `product_id` . Can I use                 `{
                  $eq: [
                    "$product_id",
                    "$product_id"
                  ]
                }`

Comment: @TahaFarooqui : In the let after productUID create another local variable productID : ‘$_id’ and use it in ‘$eq’

Comment: What did you try please post it here

Comment: @TahaFarooqui : it’s because your productID check is in or condition and since above conditions are true they’re pulling that object. You can use $and in ‘$expr’ instead of ‘$or’ and first one is this productID check and second one just paste entire ‘$or’ condition as is..

Comment: @TahaFarooqui : ok if you need three conditions has to match then use ‘$and’ instead of ‘$or’ else check my previous comment..

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your previous comment. your suggestion is working fine!! Thanks